# What is the resistance transport based on?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, spaceship

What is the resistance transport based on?

While watching Star Wars: the Force Awakens,  I couldn't help shake this feeling I'd seen the resistance transport before.

Is its design based on a previous ship from the franchise (maybe a game?) or some other movie?

[image: transport ship]

Comment: It looks like an [Eagle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Transporter).

Comment: It kind of reminds me of a modified version of the transport Anakin & Padme used when they went back to Naboo in AOTC. I don't know what that ship was called or have a link to it. Maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 7):

## It's based on modified B-Wing

[image: Text from the cross-section book]

> The odd appearance of the Resistance's transports reflects their unorthodox origins and construction. The craft have been cobbled together by Resistance technicians from a hotchpotch of systems bought, begged and stolen. Parts scrounged from scrapped B-wing Mark II's have been fitted to engine pods from Republic-era shuttles, attached to civilian passenger modules and augmented with knockoffs of hyperdrives created for the First Order. Techs bemoan frequent breakdowns but keep these ungainly craft flying, knowing they may be needed at a moment's notice.

It looks like the B-Wing makes up the cockpit of the ship, which also sits massively to the side, thus the similarity you make have noticed. On a second inspection, you may also noticed the gun on the side furthest from the cockpit is also from the B-Wing.

[image: B-Wing]

But the bulk of the ship is likely from generic civilian transports.